# JTATransactionManager Not Committing To Database

Tags: spring, hibernate, glassfish-3, spring-transactions

I will be working with a database and with a JMS queue so I decided to use JTATransactionManager (multiple resources).
I am using Spring Framework 3.2.3.RELEASE
Hibernate 4.2.1.Final
Glassfish 3.1.2.2

With JTATransactionManager nothing is committed to db.I tried JPATransactionManager it works fine.I don't get any exceptions with JTATransactionManager.Any idea what I am doing wrong?Thanks.

This is a piece of jpa config file

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="Test" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
       p:packagesToScan="com.pinkshield.jpaTest.domain" 
       p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
       p:jpaPropertyMap-ref="jpaPropertyMap" 
       p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateVendor" />


<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
    <entry key="transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />
    <entry key="transaction.manager_lookup_class"
        value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
</util:map>

<bean id="hibernateVendor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:showSql="true" />

<tx:jta-transaction-manager />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.pinkshield.jpaTest" />
```

This is my Generic Dao for JPA

```
package com.pinkshield.jpaTest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public class GenericDaoJpa<T> implements GenericDao<T> 
{

private Class<T> queryClass;
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) 
{
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}   

public GenericDaoJpa(Class<T> queryClass) 
{
    super();
    this.queryClass = queryClass;
}

public T getNewInstance() 
{
    try 
    {
        return getQueryClass().newInstance();
    } 
    catch (InstantiationException e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating new instance of : " + getQueryClass().getName(), e);
    } 
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating new instance of : " + getQueryClass().getName(), e);
    }
}

public Class<T> getQueryClass() 
{
    return queryClass;
}    

public T get(Long id) 
{
    if (id == null) 
    {
        return null;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return entityManager.find(queryClass, id);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<T> getAll() 
{
    return entityManager.createQuery("select o from " + queryClass.getName() + " o").getResultList();
}

public void save(T object) 
{
    entityManager.persist(object);
}

public void update(T object) 
{
    entityManager.merge(object);
}

public void delete(T object) 
{
    entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(object));
}
```

}

This is UserDao

```
@Repository
public class UserDao extends GenericDaoJpa<User> 
{
public UserDao() 
{
    super(User.class);
}
}
```

And this is my service code

```
 @Service
 public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService{

@Autowired UserDao userDao;

@Override
@Transactional
public void saveUser(String name, String lastName)
  { 
    User user=new User();
    user.setLastName(lastName);
    user.setName(name);

    userDao.save(user);
   }
 }
```

Comment: What package is your Service in?

Comment: @SteveHall all in the same package

Comment: @Emre I know its been a long while but, were you able to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `<tx:annotation-driven/>` to the context xml.  That will run a context post processor that will wrap methods with `@Transactional` with an AOP method interceptor that provides the transaction behavior you're looking for.

Comment: you pointed out something quite obvious that I've missed somehow.For this I am voting it but it doesn't still work with it.